# Can a Random Property on Weapons Spawn more than one Bonus?

Tags: diablo-iii

Lets take for example this [Sever Legendary Sword](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/sever)

1-Hand Legendary Sword 323.4–513.8 Damage Per Second

(165-251)–(297-483) Damage

1.40 Attacks per Second

+87-173 Minimum Damage

+116-231 Maximum Damage

+130-149 Vitality

+5-12% Damage to Demons

Critical Hit Chance Increased by 1.0%

1.0-2.6% Chance to Stun on Hit

**+1 Random Magic Properties**

Then, we have this roll here :

[image: Maybe bugged Sword ?]

Since the cap of vitality on this weapon is 149, and it has no strength spawn, i can assume that the "random property" rolled "strength".

That being said, where the others +50 vitality or so came from ?

Is this possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it can.

I Just checked this [table here](http://d3db.com/item/i/sever).
On the second page of Affixes, there these bonuses :

```
Prefix  Vigorous    +(36-120) Strength +(36-120) Vitality   
Prefix  Relentless  +(30-108) Strength +(30-108) Vitality   
Prefix  Relentless  +(33-112) Strength +(33-112) Vitality   
Prefix  Vigorous    +(39-124) Strength +(39-124) Vitality   
Prefix  Vigorous    +(42-133) Strength +(42-133) Vitality   
Prefix  Ruthless    +(45-150) Strength +(45-150) Vitality
```

So it happens that a magic property may spawn more than one attribute, this is crazy.

Comment: Damn you beat me to it. Glad my second theory is right though :D

Comment: Actually this only means that this special affix has multiple stats in it - there is still a limit on the affixes and they are balanced with this mechanic in mind.
What's even more crazy is that a gem sockets count only as one affix. So if the affix is rolled to be a socket, another roll determines how many sockets there are. (between 1 and N)

Comment: @Tigraine source for this socket math ?
So, what you are saying is that a random roll might come : "Has Socket" and the other part "+str", than, the item will ignore the "Has Sockets" part since there was no "sockets counter" rolled for that item ? Seems strange to me.

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins No what I meant is that an item has N affixes. Each is rolled independently and ALL sockets are only 1 affix. So if an item has 3 Affixes and it gets 3 Sockets it still has 2 other affixes. The number of sockets is random inside the socket affix. Source is this blue: http://www.diablofans.com/news/1212-usefulness-of-gems-legendary-gear-balancing-blue-posts-and-interview-and-review-for-the-order/

Answer (score 1):

There are only to viable options here. Either the items random property works exactly as advertised, meaning that it can range from all random properties and one gets selected for the item at random. OR the uniques have different affixes so that they can spawn with different fixed amounts for the random properties range of skills.